# Difference between "Ask me about" and "Skills"

Tags: 2013, my-site, user-profile-property

Over the last days I had a deeper look into User Profiles, My Sites and Social Features in SharePoint 2013. And I came up a bit confused about the User Profile attributes "Ask me about" and "Skills".

What is the difference between them? As far as I understand, the "Ask me about" field should contain the fields of expertise of a user, in other words his skills. So why are there two fields with extremly similar content? Are there different funtionalities bound to these fields? What would be the impact if I disable / hide one of those fields?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

their is differece between both of properties.

**Ask Me About** basically map to SPS-Responsibility user profile Proptery. Which explain, basically it is your responsibilities at the job. Which might be different from your skill set, might be you have more skills then the responsibilities.

**Skills** as display name saying, it is skills you have.